# Where to delete returned char*

Tags: c++, arrays, char, return

I have a homework assignment to implement a bulls and cows game class, our tutor gave us a header and we have to implement it, in it there's this function

```
char* TryToGuess(int);
```

What it does is it receives an int and has to return char* containing how many bulls and cows you've guessed. What I did was create a string, pass all the information in it and then convert it to a char* like so:

```
string result = "Cows:";
char c = char(cows + '0');
result += c;
result += "    Bulls:";
char b = char(bulls + '0');
result += b;
char* finalResult = new char[18];
strcpy(finalResult, result.c_str());
return finalResult;
```

We also have a function called start where we execute our game, my code for it is

```
char* result;
int guess;
do
{
    cout << "Your guess:";
    cin >> guess;
    result = TryToGuess(guess);
    cout << "\t\t\t[" << guess << "] => " << result << endl;
} while (result != "Congarulations! You made a right guess!");
cout << "\n\n\t\t It took you " << numberOfGuesses << " guesses to finish the game.\n";
```

Problem is there's a memory leak and I don't know where to put the delete[], it can't be inside the cycle because the condition in while won't be met. Thanks in advance for your help.

PS: I can't change the return type to string, my tutor has set it so.

PS2: Here's the full header

```
#ifndef BULLSANDCOWS_H_
#define BULLSANDCOWS_H_
class BullsAndCows
{
    public:
        BullsAndCows(int = 4);
        BullsAndCows(int[], int);

        void SetContainerSize(int);
        void SetContainer(int*);

        bool IsInsideContainer(int);
        bool CowElement(int*, int, int);
        bool BullElement(int*, int, int);
        char* TryToGuess(int);
        void start();

       // void print();

    private:
        int sizeOfContainer;
        int* numbersContainer;
        int numberOfGuesses;
};

#endif // BULLSANDCOWS_H_
```

Comment: `char c = char(cows + '0');` is there a `cows` variable ?

Comment: yes there is, that's just the end of the code, and I know for sure it's only a one digit number

Comment: Seems strange to be using `std::string` internally within the function, then go back to `char*` for the result. Also, the way you're converting `cows` and `bulls` to characters will only work if there are less than 10 of each.

Comment: Can you show the complete header? Also, I suspect you're being taught bad habits (the fact that this seems to be [tag:c++] given the `cout` usage, but then you're being asked to work in terms of raw pointers would indicate this)

Comment: 1)  You can't compare ``char*`` with ``==``, like you do in ``while`` condition, use ``strcmp``. 2) In this case there is no one line solution. You can initialize ``result`` with ``NULL``, put ``if`` condition in the beginning of the loop, if ``result`` is not null, then do ``delete``. 3) Also you need to correctly allocate memory. The size of the string is not always 18.

Comment: class BullsAndCows
{
    public:
        BullsAndCows(int = 4);
        BullsAndCows(int[], int);

        void SetContainerSize(int);
        void SetContainer(int*);

        bool IsInsideContainer(int);
        bool CowElement(int*, int, int);
        bool BullElement(int*, int, int);
        char* TryToGuess(int);
        void start();

       // void print();

    private:
        int sizeOfContainer;
        int* numbersContainer;
        int numberOfGuesses;
};

Comment: any way I can separate them :/

Comment: @Robert Don't put code in comments, edit the question.

Comment: @Robert - there's an edit link (bottom left, below tags). You can't show code in comments but you can improve your *question*

Comment: Damien could you please explain more about these bad habits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `delete result[]` each time through the loop, after you're done using it. Otherwise, you'll leak that memory the next time you assign to the variable. But this also means that you can't use `result` in the `while` clause, because it has already been deleted. You'll have to test this inside the loop.

```
bool done = false;
do
{
    cout << "Your guess:";
    cin >> guess;
    result = TryToGuess(guess);
    cout << "\t\t\t[" << guess << "] => " << result << endl;
    done = strcmp(result, "Congarulations! You made a right guess!") == 0;
    delete result[];
} while (!done);
```

Note also that you don't use `==` to compare C strings (it will compare the pointer values, not the contents of the strings), you must use `strcmp`.

Comment: You delete variable, and then check if it's equals to something.

Comment: I admit I'm rusty but isn't this the moral equivalent of use after free?

Comment: Thank you and Nikolay, now it works fine, no mem leak :)